# Is playing electronic music on a custom set of instruments a feasible way of live performance for a culture?

Tags: internal-consistency, culture, technological-development, adaptability, music

I love electronic music in various subgenres, and I really often wish I could see the tracks performing on instruments in a way that makes it much more theatrical and visually appealing.

Of course, great composers are often able to provide faithul covers on string or keyboard instruments, which might be an option.

But in a world where technological advancement had different developing ways and the culture also adapted it differently, it might make sense to create instruments that, by the synchronous performance of multiple individuals, can produce music that we may indentify as trance, acid or maybe even dubstep. (I mean, Dilinger Escape Plan is not even that far from it...)

What circumstances and factors makes this idea feasible and/or unfeasible?

Comment: ...Have we not made instruments that can play trance, acid or dubstep? Launchpads, electric keyboards, DJ booths, etc, etc... If I'm not mistaken people go see DJs perform at events called "concerts". So.. am I not understanding the question? Or did it originate from a strange parallel universe where none of that exists?

Comment: @AngelPray, let me quote myself: *in a way that makes it much more theatrical and visually appealing* - one may argue about the precise definition of it, but what I would consider meeting these criteria are usually portable tools, with very little wires to mean an obstacle: such as a guitar or a microphone.

Comment: So, like a Jean-Michel Jarre show? That would certainly qualify as electronic music and visually appealing.

Comment: @AmiralPatate maybe even that may qualify.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see much of a problem with it. The only difficulty I can think of is the butterfly effect - small changes become bigger over time. Namely, if technology and culture developed differently, it would be extremely unlikely to see the same styles of music appearing. However, considering how common music and technology in general are among human cultures, I think it is reasonable to say that even in an alternate history, there could be music and people would eventually try using technology in music somehow. Through chance and/or the limited number of possible forms of music, there may even be some similarities between their styles and ours. So, unless there's something I'm missing, it should work.

Comment: Of course, same music genres are not a criteria here. This I worded like *we may indentify as...*

Answer (score 2):

If it is electric technology it would, in my opinion, take related forms of what we see now.

You should really have a look at the concerts from *The Glitch Mob*, their performances could be a hint of what you are looking for.

For creating electric music live you need to use a synthesizer or are pre programmed launchpad. It makes MUCH more sense to create a controller to distort a guitar to sound like dubstep then to create a dubstep guitar.

But if there was not any instruments until technology came, you can do whatever you want. Otherwise I think you have to include drum and string instruments, because those are just the most natural to create. (Every from of culture created their own kind of drum and string instruments.)

But in their vidoes you should see that anyone in the band is standing in front of a deck of controller and pads. Without this the only way to make the music live would be a mp3 file... (early Skrillex, running his song on windows media player and jumping around like a madman).

You could make it a lot cooler though: let their decks float around with magnets so the artist can move with it, hell, why don't even put the artist on a magnetic disc and let him and the deck fly around?

And live drums are always better than recorded ones.

Play around with distorted singing voices in the track. Artists all over the world are starting to create their dream language and sing with it.

But light shows and the general feel of the performance is way more important (in electronic music) than the artist looking cool, in my opinion.

Another thing might interest you: take a look at the song *Unsustainable* from *Muse*. Dubstep made with a normal band setup, but with very hard computer distortion. You could simply make rock'n'roll stars to dubstep stars, just by using different effectors. Then Bellamy from *Muse* got a weird guitar like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jKa_0xnTfU). He can program the touchpad to do whatever a computer can do with sound.

Lastly, probably the most interesting for you is [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0UfL6QAeXA).
You could equip artists with these everywhere, let them dance and create music with their dance.

//E Totally forgot about loop artists. Check out *Tash Sultana* and *Dub FX*